# Font-size on SVG on Android

Tags: android, svg, font-size, tablet

**To reproduce the problem:**

**Copy/Paste this code to HTML File:**

```
<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 168.159 80.635" >
    <text x="33.06" font-size="1" y="10.385" fill="#000000" stroke="none">Little(1)</text>
    <text x="33.42" font-size="3" y="20.913" fill="#000000" stroke="none">Normal(3)</text>
    <text x="33.292" font-size="7" y="30.344" fill="#000000" stroke="none">Big(7)</text>
    <text x="33.292" font-size="15" y="50.344" fill="#000000" stroke="none">Very Big(15)</text>
</svg>
```

**Launch the HTML File in your tablet or smartphone** (*I use Cordova*).

The text *"Little", "Normal", "Big"* are the same size(about 9). *"Very Big"* has the good size(15).

No problem in PC: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/116366pbsvgpc.png

But on Android tablet: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/925902pbsvgandroid.png

Can you reproduce this problem?
Have you an idea to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your chosen font is available to the Android browser or it may replace it with Droid font.
I guess your font-sizes are in "px". A single pixel is not reasonable for a font-size. Units should be declared, so consider starting with

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 168.159 800.635" >
    <text x="33.06" font-size="10px" y="100.385" fill="#000000" stroke="none">Little(1)</text>
    <text x="33.42" font-size="30px" y="200.913" fill="#000000" stroke="none">Normal(3)</text>
    <text x="33.292" font-size="70px" y="300.344" fill="#000000" stroke="none">Big(7)</text>
    <text x="33.292" font-size="150px" y="500.344" fill="#000000" stroke="none">Very Big(15)</text>
    </svg>
```

Comment: I don't know very well SVG but I think if we don't specify units, it's a relative size, like x (it's not px too).
I don't specify the font so it should be an available font.
And above all, why it works for size 15 and not for size under 9?

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong there. A font-size attribute without units in SVG is in pixels. I.e. 15 and 15px are exactly the same.

Comment: Also why, when I extend the window, the text(and all the picture proportionally) gets bigger in PC?
I edit the question to add link of pictures.

Comment: If you have a separate/different question it's best to ask a separate/different question.

Comment: Anyway, add "px" do nothing. The problem remains the same !
But you don't help me very well... Can you reproduce the problem or not in your android tablet/smartphone? Is it a known problem or is it specific cordova or...?